# set locale - thousands sep, decimal point etc

Tags: node.js

How is it possible to get locale environment variables in nodejs?

In PHP you can set the locale `setLocale(LC_MONETARY, $locale);` and then call `localeconv()` to get the variables..

Comment: How do you then set the locale eg `da`, `de` etc?!

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong duplicate question. See [this one about internationalization](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) instead.

Comment: What meaning would this have in NodeJS anyway? NodeJS has no notion of internationalization and is rather bare-bones. Do you mean with something like express?

Comment: What I need is to get locale environment vars like `decimal_point` and `thousands_sep` on each request in express.. On each request the language like `da` or `de` is set and then I need to retrieve the locale vars